# Error while trying to connect salesforce through Eclipse IDE. Any suggestions?

Tags: eclipse

Suddenly i got an error when i try to execute an anonymous code and this is the error screen i got below. Alternatively i also tried to create a new salesforce project and got the same error.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to switch to [MavensMate](http://mavensmate.com/)! I changed a few months ago and I have been loving it!

However, sticking with Eclipse, my guess would be that something got messed up in the cached data that Eclipse and its extensions uses. I would try running eclipse with the [`-clean` parameter](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Frunning_eclipse.htm) set.

> `-clean`
>
> Cleans cached data used by the OSGi framework and Eclipse runtime. Try
>   to run Eclipse once with this option if you observe startup errors
>   after install, update, or using a shared configuration.

Here is some more info on [running `-clean` mode from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2030064/2005002).

Comment: Thanks Jesse. Would Mavensmate work in Windows xp professional? i am having win xp.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. I have a Mac. Here are the installation instructions for Windows if you want to try it - http://mavensmate.com/Plugins/Sublime_Text/Installation#windows. By the way, I would seriously consider upgrading from Windows XP. That operating system has gone EOL (End of Life) and security will be an issue http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/end-support-help

Comment: Thanks, i would give a try. Also, thanks for additional info regarding EOL.